# Number of menu button that is guaranteed to be shown in ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

I did quite a lot of research, but couldn't find an answer for this one. The main quote I am starting from, is from the official android developer site:

```
"If you believe that more than four of your menu items can be  justified as action items[...]"
```

This indicates me, I can safely use 4 menu buttons. At the moment, I am using 3 menu buttons on my main screen, but by popular demand, I am refactoring the mentioned main screen, which causes the need of exactly 4 menu item buttons.

My question is: are 4 standard size, only image buttons are guaranteed to be shown at ALL times, on EVERY device? So the top of the screen would look something like this in ALL cases:

```
_____________________________
|[I] ASD     [1] [2] [3] [4]|
-----------------------------
```

Where [I] is the App icon, "ASD" is the label of the Activity(which is exactly 3 letters), [1], [2], [3], [4] are the menubuttons, each of them is a simple image.

Thanks in advance, cheers.

Comment: I think it should relay on the space on ActionBar... if You dig more you realise that there `showAsAction="ifRoom"` what it does that.. if you added many menus with this attributes it shows all those menu in actionbar as much space is available, and left menus get placed at bottom as default...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This indicates me, I can safely use 4 menu buttons

I think you are reading too much into that sentence, wherever you got it from.

> are 4 standard size, only image buttons are guaranteed to be shown at ALL times, on EVERY device?

No.

First, device manufacturers can tinker with Android and may affect the behavior of the action bar on their devices. Now, the odds are that they will leave this alone, but "odds are" != "guaranteed". Even if the number of action bar items were mandated as part of compatibility testing (and AFAIK it is not), there are device manufacturers exempt from such testing because they do not license the Play Store or other Google commercial apps.

Second, on a `-small` screen device, four buttons might well be too many. *Two* might be too many, in portrait at least. I have not experimented with either ActionBarSherlock or the native API Level 11+ action bar on a `-small` device recently and so do not know how many action bar items it supports.

Moreover, any action bar items that do not fit into the action bar will go into the overflow (triggered via the MENU button on devices that have them or a "..." affordance in the action bar for those that don't), so the user can still access those things even if the icons are not visible for one reason or another.

Comment: Yea, I may read too much into that, that is exactly why I asked it. anyway, it is from developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html . I do use the ActionBarSherlock, so the manufacturer tinkering is irrelevant in this case.

I was indeed afraid of the -small devices, guess I will stick to the 3 buttons, which is working very well for now, and find another place for the fourth button. Thanks!

Comment: @hundeva: "I do use the ActionBarSherlock, so the manufacturer tinkering is irrelevant in this case" -- bear in mind that ABS passes everything through to the native action bar on API Level 14+. Hence, manufacturer tinkering on such devices will be relevant, where it occurs. "I was indeed afraid of the -small devices" -- you need to test it. It's conceivable that four is supported, though I think that'd be much too cramped. Again, it's more an area of concern. Also, `-small` devices are perhaps more likely to be tinkered with by manufacturers, as are any devices that test Android's boundaries.

Comment: Hm, I was not aware of the usage of the native ActionBar on API Level 14+ devices, that is nice to know. :)